# Check if web file exists, without downloading it?

Tags: ruby

Is it somehow possible to check if a file exists, without actually downloading it?

I have this large (~ *40mb*) file,  for example:

> http://mirrors.sohu.com/mysql/MySQL-6.0/MySQL-6.0.11-0.glibc23.src.rpm

This is *not* strictly related to ruby, but it would be nice if the sender could set the content length.

```
RestClient.get "http://mirrors.sohu.com/mysql/MySQL-6.0/MySQL-6.0.11-0.glibc23.src.rpm", 
               headers: {"Content-Length" => 100}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `RestClient.head`. (See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-head)

> The HTTP HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT send content in the response. HEAD is used to obtain metadata about the selected representation without transferring its representation data, often for the sake of testing hypertext links or finding recent modifications.

[RFC 9110 HTTP Semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html)

Comment: Yes, and it's 15 sec before I can give you the *OK*. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

See section 9.4 regarding the HEAD request.

Answer (score 1):

**We can use wget:**

```
  def file_exists?(full_file_path)
      resp = `wget --spider -v #{full_file_path} && echo 1 || echo 0`
      resp.to_i.zero? ? false : true
  end
```